# Async Operation In Destructor

Tags: c#, asynchronous, destructor

Trying to run async operation in class destructor is fail.

This is the code:

```
public class Executor
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var c1 = new Class1();

            c1.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public class Class1 
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {

        }

        private int _i = 100;
        private int _j = 100;

        ~Class1()
        {
            Task.Run(() => _j *= 2); //Does not progress _j
            _i *= 2; //Progress _i from 100 to 200

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("In destructor. _i = " + _i);
            Console.WriteLine("In destructor. _j =  " + _j);
        }
    }
```

And the output is:

```
In destructor. _i = 200
In destructor. _j =  100
```

Following [Destructor page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) does not mention threads/async aspects of instance destruction.

So any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `Task.Run` will kick off another thread but even if you wait 1 second maybe that is not enough. You need to wait for the result of the task maybe using `.Wait()` to ensure it completes. That said I think starting threads or tasks in the destructor is a bad idea. Destructors should be used to cleanup unmanaged memory.

Comment: wow, what an idea to pass a reference to another thread after GC obviously put that reference into the finalizer queue already...

Comment: @RenéVogt The documentation explicitly mentions that the code in the destructor is executed prior to finalizing the object. see the bottom of this anchor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx#Remarks

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible, but - well - strange.... In your example, the destructor is not (afaik) called by the gc, but because your program terminates. I'm not sure if `Task.Run()` is really able to acquire a thread from the threadpool at this point of execution/termination.

Comment: @RenéVogt Sure - I totally understand your point and you are right, the case refers to very specific situation that lead me to raise this question as I could not find any information about it. Thank you for your comments :)

Comment: If you want to run something async before the destructor completes, at the very least you need to await the result.

Comment: In general I understand, in the mentioned example - would 1000 milisec are not not enough?

Answer (score 3):

In your particular example new thread cannot be started because runtime is terminating and app domain is unloading. When app domain unloads - it will run all finalizers and shutdown all threads. You can verify this with:

```
Console.WriteLine("shutdown:" + Environment.HasShutdownStarted);
```

Which will return `true` in your case. If you modify you example like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var c1 = new Class1();
        c1.DoSomething();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }        
}

public class Class1
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }

    private volatile int _i = 100;
    private volatile int _j = 100;

    ~Class1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("shutdown:" + Environment.HasShutdownStarted);
        Task.Run(() => _j *= 2); //Does not progress _j
        //_i *= 2; //Progress _i from 100 to 200            
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("In destructor. _i = " + _i);
        Console.WriteLine("In destructor. _j =  " + _j);
    }
}
```

And compile in Release mode with optimizations - you will see that now runtime is not terminating and your task will run fine.

Obviously you should never do such things in finalizer, but just so that you know the real reason.

Comment: Your answer fits the problem, yet - are you familiar with any official documentation regard this issue? Thank you

Comment: I think it is quite obvious that when runtime terminates (so your process is exiting) it makes no sense to allow starting new threads and all running threads are aborted? However I will try to find something on documentation.

Comment: @SaturnTechnologies unfortunately I was not able to find any specific documentation about this case in the limited time I had for that.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts and time